# Saving OnetoOneField in Django Admin while null=True gives error

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have OnetoOnefield in my model, which is set to null=True and blank=True. Everything is working fine but as soon as I try to save that model's object from admin site I get IntegrityError, saying that the field can't be null.

My model is:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    doctor = models.OneToOneField(Doctor)
    clinic = models.OneToOneField(Clinic, null=True, blank=True)
    hospital = models.OneToOneField(Hospital, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message (with full stack trace)? `Appointment.doctor` has `blank=False, null=False`. Is the `IntegrityError` related to that field?

Comment: I have to populate either the 'clinic' or the 'hospital' for a given appointment, but whenever I leave any one of those fields empty. I get the error saying that this field can't be null. While both of them are marked null=True.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this field.

```
doctor = models.OneToOneField(Doctor)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    doctor = models.OneToOneField(Doctor)
    clinic = models.OneToOneField(Clinic, null=True, blank=True)
    hospital = models.OneToOneField(Hospital, null=True, blank=True)
```